# iOS label does not update text with the string value, but print the string works correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been searching for the last two days to resolve this issue. the part of code that I am having the issue with is: `[say practiceLabelVar gets the value optional(Goldfish)]`

```
class PracticeTyping: UIViewController {   
    @IBOutlet weak var practiceLabel: UILabel!

    var practiceLabelVar: String?
    var x = "test"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     if let newPracticeLabelVar = practiceLabelVar {

            self.practiceLabel.text = newPracticeLabelVar

            print ("\(newPracticeLabelVar)")

            x = newPracticeLabelVar

        } else {

            print ("\(x)")

        }     
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is as follows in the console :

```
test

Goldfish
```

Note: the code prints the value in the else statement then prints the code in the if let statement.

The `practiceLabel.text` did not change and kept its default value.

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: where are u assigning "Goldfish" to practiceLabelVar ??  The reason it is going to else is because u have not assigned any value to practiceLabelVar variable.

Comment: I am assigning the value Goldfish from a table view controller in another view. when I click a button the     @IBAction func practiceTyping(_ sender: Any) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "practiceTypingSegue", sender: self)

        

        let PracticeTypingVar: PracticeTyping = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PracticeTypingView") as! PracticeTyping



        PracticeTypingVar.practiceLabelVar = myFavoriteAnimals[(sender as AnyObject).tag].name

        

        self.present(PracticeTypingVar, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out. Based on the comment you have added above, you are setting "Goldfish" from another view and as mentioned, below is the code for the same `@IBAction func practiceTyping(_ sender: Any) {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "practiceTypingSegue", sender: self)
let PracticeTypingVar: PracticeTyping = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PracticeTypingView") as! PracticeTyping 
PracticeTypingVar.practiceLabelVar = myFavoriteAnimals[(sender as AnyObject).tag].name 
self.present(PracticeTypingVar, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}`

What you are doing here is you are that you are presenting "PracticeTyping" viewController 2 times, one with performSegue() and other with self.present(viewController) which is wrong. The reason why it is printing "test" first is that u are not setting the value for "practiceLabelVar" when u are presenting the view via performSegue.
So remove `performSegue(withIdentifier: "practiceTypingSegue", sender: self)` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to request you to kindly understand what is [Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

The code is running fine it just checks if there is value in there or not and yes there is not value so off course the else condition will be executed. Try to assign some value and you will understand how it works

Note: There is no value in `var practiceLabelVar: String?` if there is some value in it, if let will work or else will execute

Comment: the value for practiceLabelVar comes from a tabelView and the code prints the correct value that I am looking for. my issue now is to get this value in the practiceLabel.text              Thank you